# Include MPChartLib in Android project

Tags: android, android-library, mpandroidchart

I have downloaded the [MPChartLib library](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/releases/tag/v3.0.3) as zip file.I use Android Studio 1.5

Answer (score 3):

> Gradle dependency (recommended)

Add the following to your project level build.gradle:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}
```

Add this to your app build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.3'
}
```

Visit [MP Android Chard Usage](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart#usage) for more details

Answer (score 2):

Compile this in your build.gradle file-:

```
compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v2.2.4'

repositories {
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}
```

Create layout using this-:

```
<com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.PieChart
        android:id="@+id/piechart"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Use this Link for Further Reference-:
https://www.studytutorial.in/android-pie-chart-using-mpandroid-library-tutorial

Comment: Depending on the version of Gradle, this may be `implementation` instead of `compile`

Comment: That inculdes in Android 3.0 and read the question can install 3.0 so its an alternative..

Answer (score 1):

Just browse what is the content of the ZIP file, if its a jar you can unzip and import it Pressing Ctrl+Alt+Shift+S and selecting the Plus Sign in the Libraries menu